# cx_Oracle: Format output

Tags: python, oracle, unix, cx-oracle

Hello I'm writing a script which will get data from a Oracle DB.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#add paths for additional libraries
import sys
sys.path.append('/app/zhunix/python/lib')
import cx_Oracle

user = '*****'
passwd = '******'
sid = '*******'
host = '**********'
port = '*******'
dsn_tns =  cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid)

db = cx_Oracle.connect(user, passwd, dsn_tns)
print("Database Version: " +  db.version)
fqdn = raw_input("Hostname: ")


var = """select USY_MAIN_FQDN,USY_SYS_ID,USY_SYS_NAME,USY_SYS_MEMORY,USY_SYS_PROCESSORS from IFC_UNIXINFRA.IFC_UNIXINFRA_SYSTEM_V where USY_SYS_NAME like ('%s')""" % fqdn

cur = db.cursor()

dbora = cur.execute(var)

for row in dbora:
        print (row)

cur.close()
db.close()
```

Now when I print " row " it comes out like this (censored):

```
('servername.com', 1390863, 'servername', 147456, 8)
```

How I can make a print which looks like that?

```
FQDN:       servername.com
ID:         1390863
Hostname:   servername
Memory:     147456
Processors: 8
```

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: Is dictionary is what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
labels = ('FQDN:', 'ID: ', 'Hostname:','Memory:','Processors:')
for row in dbora:
    for idx,el in enumerate(row): 
        print labels[idx] + ': ' + str(el)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked! Do you also probably know how to make the same space between the title and result for all?

Comment: @lyenuas You could left justify the label part...e.g.  `print (labels[idx] + ':').ljust(20) + str(s)`

Comment: Thank you so much!